# Get size of SqlDataReader payload

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to figure out the size of the payload that gets returned from SQL Server. The code I have is using ADO.NET:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products]", connection))
{
  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
  // find # of bytes of payload returned
```

However, I am unsure how to get the size of what got returned from SQL server. Is there a way using the `SqlDataReader` I can do that?

Comment: In many cases you can't -- because the reader will stream data as it's read.

Comment: I have never tried this. I would use count(*) instead of select * from products instead. Then, estimate the memory based on the data types of the columns ?

Comment: It looks like it will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the query below. Replace the shop by your table name and id by your column name.

```
DECLARE @maxRowSize int
SET @maxRowSize =
(
SELECT SUM(DataSize) AS MaxRowSize
FROM
(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as DataSize
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'shop' -- enter table name only, do NOT enter the schema
) AS SCHEM
)
SELECT COUNT(Id) as NumOfRows, --optional
@maxRowSize as MaxRowBytes, --optional
COUNT(id) * @maxRowSize as MaxQueryBytes
FROM Shop -- Enter schema name if needed
```

Comment: Another query to get the table info - `SELECT column_name as 'Column Name', 
data_type as 'Data Type',
character_maximum_length as 'Max Length'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'shop' `

Comment: I created a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518384/how-do-i-get-the-maximum-memory-consumed-by-all-data-types-in-sql-server